Render Props vs React Hooks for Dynamic children Layout
What use cases does React hooks not cover when using it as a replacement of the render-props pattern? Any practical examples?
I have an App with three Lists, the idea is to create a generic component to add virtualization in my app. The ability to pass different row styles/classes and elements is a must.
I have two implementations, is there any issues with either implementation? which one would you choose? why?
List 1 and List 2 use the same approach, just for illustration purposes, we have 2. List 3 is simplified to use a hook, rows are passed in the hook options. Components/List and hooks/useVirtalizer.jsx are using approach 1 (I know I can not complicate stuff and keep the logic inside List.jsx only, but assuming I have much more logic, I split it into a hook as well)
hooks/useVirtualizerAllHooks.jsx is using approach 2.
src/
  ├── App.jsx
  ├── components/
  │   └── List.jsx
  ├── hooks/
  │   ├── useVirtualizer.jsx
  │   └── useVirtualizerAllHooks.jsx
  └── data.js

import React from 'react';
import List from './components/List.jsx';
import useVirtualizerAllHooks from './hooks/useVirtualizerAllHooks.jsx';
import { DATA1, DATA2 } from './data.js';

export function App(props) {
  const ListWrapper = useVirtualizerAllHooks({
    row: (item) => {
      return (
        <li key={DATA1[item.index].id}>
          <h1>{DATA1[item.index].name}</h1>
        </li>
      );
    },
    items: DATA1,
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>List One</p>
      <List items={DATA1}>
        {(item) => (
          <li key={DATA1[item.index].id}>
            <p>{DATA1[item.index].name}</p>
          </li>
        )}
      </List>

      <p>List Two (Different styles & functionality)</p>
      <List items={DATA2}>
        {(item) => (
          <li key={DATA2[item.index].id}>
            <p>{DATA2[item.index].name}</p>
            <button>dumdum</button>
          </li>
        )}
      </List>

      <p>List Three (All Hooks)</p>
      <ListWrapper />
    </div>
  );
}

List
import useVirtualizer from '../hooks/useVirtualizer.jsx';

export default function List(props) {
  const { children, items } = props;

  const { rows, parentRefInit } = useVirtualizer({ items });

  return (
    <ul ref={parentRefInit} style={{ height: 150, overflowY: 'auto' }}>
      {rows.map((item) => children(item))}
    </ul>
  );
}

data
export const DATA1 = Array.from({ length: 50 }, (v, i) => ({
  id: i + 1,
  name: `fake data ${i + 1}`
}));

export const DATA2 = Array.from({ length: 50 }, (v, i) => ({
  id: i + 1,
  name: `fake data2 ${i + 1}`
}));

useVirtualizer
import { useWindowVirtualizer } from '@tanstack/react-virtual'
import { useCallback, useRef } from 'react'

export default function useVirtualizer({ items }) {
  const parentRef = useRef(null)

  const parentRefInit = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      parentRef.current = node
    }
  }, [])

  const virtualizer = useWindowVirtualizer({
    count: items.length,
    estimateSize: () => 50,
    overscan:  5,
    scrollMargin: parentRef.current?.offsetTop ?? 0,
  })

  return { rows: virtualizer.getVirtualItems(), parentRefInit }
}

useVirtualizerAllHooks
import { useWindowVirtualizer } from '@tanstack/react-virtual'
import { useCallback, useRef } from 'react'

export default function useVirtualizer({ row, items }) {
  const parentRef = useRef(null)

  const parentRefInit = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      parentRef.current = node
    }
  }, [])

  const virtualizer = useWindowVirtualizer({
    count: items.length,
    estimateSize: () => 50,
    overscan:  5,
    scrollMargin: parentRef.current?.offsetTop ?? 0,
  })

  const List = () => {
    if (virtualizer.getVirtualItems().length <= 0) return
    return (
      <ul ref={parentRefInit} style={{ height: 150, overflowY: 'auto' }}>
        {virtualizer.getVirtualItems().map((item) => row(item))}
      </ul>
    )
  }

  return List
}


useVirtualizerAllHooks example is antithetical to react and invalid since using that hook results in a component being redefined in render, which will cause perf and state persistence issues. Components like List must be defined at the top level of an ESM  module, and can not be defined inside another component. Being inside a hook like this, is still this -- by proxy. Hooks are a means for state composition., not component composition (which crucially has opinion on presentation). Render props is a means for component composition. Component composition is a superset of state composition.

@adsy I can define the component outside of App component avoiding your concerns and pass its reference, no? Mind sharing references?
